# Passing state downstream in a Flux

Tags: java, flux, reactor

I recently implemented a CSV parser in which I used `switchOnFirst` to extract the header, which then is passed along in an `AtomicReference`.
Here is a simplified version:

```java
Flux<String> lines = Flux.just("HEADER", "line1", "line2", "line3", "line4");

AtomicReference<String> header = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

lines.switchOnFirst((sig, flux) -> {
        String item = sig.get();
        if (sig.isOnNext() && item != null) {
            header.set(item);
            return flux.skip(1);
        } 
        return Flux.error(() -> new RuntimeException("No header was found"));
})
.flatMap(line -> Mono.just(header.get() + ":" + line))
.doOnNext(x -> count.incrementAndGet())
.subscribe(
        System.out::println,
        System.err::println,
        () -> System.out.println(count.get() + " rows processed")
);
```

I am aware that there is `Flux.deferContextual(..)`, but I didn't figure out how to read context data from the subscription (to print out "X rows processed").

Is there a best practises for this?
Would the capturing atomic references approach above still be a better fit?

I tried to look for information around `switchOnFirst` and `Flux.deferContextual(..)` but I haven't found anything that suggests what the best practises is for this particular scenario in which I am trying to:

- 1st parse a header that has to be passed downstream or somehow be made available to downstream emissions
- 2nd include a count of emissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a count of the number of items processed, it looks like the `count()` operator would work:

```
                ...
                .flatMap(line -> Mono.just(header.get() + ":" + line))
                .count()
                .doOnNext(x -> System.out.println(x + " count() rows processed"))
                .subscribe(
                        System.out::println,
                        System.err::println);
```

Comment: `count()` did the job for me, at least for the "happy path" in which there weren't any errors. In other words, if the chain processed up to 3 out of 4 lines, and failed while processing "line4", I would not be able to print that 3 lines have been processed.